# What's the "collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status" in cross compile

Tags: nvidia, make, arm, cross-compilation

When trying to cross compile the CUDNN samples:

```
cp -r /usr/src/cudnn_samples_v8/ $HOME
cd  $HOME/cudnn_samples_v8/mnistCUDNN
make clean
make TARGET_ARCH=aarch64 SBSA=1
```

Here is the error:

```
CUDA_VERSION is 12020
Linking agains cublasLt = true
CUDA VERSION: 12020
TARGET ARCH: aarch64
HOST_ARCH: x86_64
TARGET OS: linux
nvlink warning : Skipping incompatible '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudadevrt.a' when searching for -lcudadevrt
nvlink warning : Skipping incompatible '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudadevrt.a' when searching for -lcudadevrt
nvlink warning : Skipping incompatible '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudadevrt.a' when searching for -lcudadevrt
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcublasLt.so when searching for -lcublasLt
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcublasLt.so when searching for -lcublasLt
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcublasLt.so when searching for -lcublasLt
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so when searching for -lcudart
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so when searching for -lcudart
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so when searching for -lcudart
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcublas.so when searching for -lcublas
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcublas.so when searching for -lcublas
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcublas.so when searching for -lcublas
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lfreeimage: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lfreeimage: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudadevrt.a when searching for -lcudadevrt
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudadevrt.a when searching for -lcudadevrt
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudadevrt.a when searching for -lcudadevrt
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart_static.a when searching for -lcudart_static
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart_static.a when searching for -lcudart_static
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart_static.a when searching for -lcudart_static
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>>> WARNING - FreeImage is not set up correctly. Please ensure FreeImage is set up correctly. <<<
[@] /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -IFreeImage/include -ccbin aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ -m64 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_53,code=sm_53 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 -gencode arch=compute_62,code=sm_62 -gencode arch=compute_70,code=sm_70 -gencode arch=compute_72,code=sm_72 -gencode arch=compute_75,code=sm_75 -gencode arch=compute_80,code=sm_80 -gencode arch=compute_86,code=sm_86 -gencode arch=compute_87,code=sm_87 -gencode arch=compute_90,code=sm_90 -gencode arch=compute_90,code=compute_90 -o fp16_dev.o -c fp16_dev.cu
[@] aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -IFreeImage/include -o fp16_emu.o -c fp16_emu.cpp
[@] aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -IFreeImage/include -o mnistCUDNN.o -c mnistCUDNN.cpp
[@] /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -ccbin aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ -m64 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_53,code=sm_53 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 -gencode arch=compute_62,code=sm_62 -gencode arch=compute_70,code=sm_70 -gencode arch=compute_72,code=sm_72 -gencode arch=compute_75,code=sm_75 -gencode arch=compute_80,code=sm_80 -gencode arch=compute_86,code=sm_86 -gencode arch=compute_87,code=sm_87 -gencode arch=compute_90,code=sm_90 -gencode arch=compute_90,code=compute_90 -o mnistCUDNN fp16_dev.o fp16_emu.o mnistCUDNN.o -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -IFreeImage/include -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcublasLt -LFreeImage/lib/linux/aarch64 -LFreeImage/lib/linux -lcudart -lcublas -lcudnn -lfreeimage -lstdc++ -lm
```

The libfreeimage3 libfreeimage-dev are already installed:

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/freeimage-is-not-set-up-correctly-please-ensure-freeimae-is-set-up-correctly/66950/2

What's the "`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`" in the above output?
How to find the cause?

Answer (score 3):

The [GNU linker(*`ld`*)](https://manned.org/ld.1) is a tool(*one of many*) invoked during the compilation process to create an executable from object files created/called in your project.

[`collect2`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Collect2.html) is the tool collecting/inspecting the linker's output.

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

simply mean the above linking operation didn't succeed, but it's not the actual cause casing your compilation operation to fail, but rather a consequent result of previous errors and it's those errors that you need to mind ... For example:

```
cannot find -lfreeimage: No such file or directory
```

With further info in:

```
>>> WARNING - FreeImage is not set up correctly. Please ensure FreeImage is set up correctly. <<<
```

Notice: that `libfreeimage` availability on your system might not be the one and only cause for that error, but it could be needing some other related libraries like for example `libcudnn`(*inspired partly by you tagging your question with `nvidia`*) depending on your project.